# How to do math operations in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, math, operation

It seems easy, but I get always 0 when i run the math operations in my flutter app.
I did the same in Java with success, but i'm sure it is slightly different in flutter.
Basically, after run the operation, the button will execute the `add` method and put the result on a textfield.

Something i also don't get it, if my variables are defined as `double`, why then i need to say again "ris1 = (q1 ~/ sum) as double;" ?

I am trying to run this:( i just wrote the essential code, because it is too big)

```
class _CalcolaWState extends State<CalcolaW> {


TextEditingController _textEditingController = TextEditingController();

double q1 = 0, q2 = 0, f1 = 0, f2=0;
double sum = 0, ris1=0, ris2 = 0, ris3 = 0, ris4= 0, ris5=0;

add() {
setState((){
    f1 = double.parse(_textEditingController.text);
    q1 = double.parse(_textEditingController2.text);
    f2 = double.parse(_textEditingController3.text);
    q2 = double.parse(_textEditingController4.text);

    sum = (q1 + q2);
      
    ris1 = (q1 ~/ sum) as double;
      
    ris2 = (q2 ~/ sum) as double;

    ris3 = f1 * ris1;
    ris4 = f2 * ris2;
    ris5 = ris3 + ris4;

    });
    }
    CupertinoTextField(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
        keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
        controller: _textEditingController,
        placeholder: 'Enter 1st Flour Strenght ' ,
        placeholderStyle: TextStyle(color: cursorColor),
        ),
    ),
    ElevatedButton(
        child: Text("Calculate"),
        style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
        primary: Colors.green,
        ),
        onPressed: (){
        add();
        _controller.text = '$ris5';
        print(ris5);
        }
```

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/math_expressions/example. This package can solve operations using strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`~/` operator returns integer, use `/` for double

> ~/    Divide, returning an integer result

See [Arithmetic operators](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#arithmetic-operators).